# python directories in ubuntu 18.04 LTS /usr/lib/ fresh install

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and realized that the /usr/lib/ directory is populated with the following python directories (I have not installed any python packages manually):

python2.7/
python3/
python3.6/
python3.7/

From my understanding, Ubuntu 18.04 installs python3 by [default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Other_base_system_changes_since_16.04_LTS) and this is confirmed by the terminal:

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Meanwhile no python2 seems to be installed.

```sh
$ python --version
Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:
...
```

```sh
$ which python
(empty)
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is there python2.7/ in /usr/lib/ if it was not installed?
2. Why are there three different python3 directories in /usr/lib/?

Edit: I have not installed or uninstalled any python packages manually.

Comment: Have you tried `which python2`?

Comment: why pythonX/ appear in /usr/lib ? Mine are in /usr/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To find where Py2 is installed:

```
which python
```

This would return the location of where Python 2 is installed.
However it looks like you don't have Py2 installed that's why `python --version` doesn't return anything but instead asks you to install Python 2.

The files are just remnants of the previous install, existence of those directories doesn't imply that you can run Py2. Several applications choose to not remove the directories in order to preserve configs in case the application is reinstalled again.

2) Many Python application were built using the earlier versions of Python and will not work with newer Python versions. So on Ubuntu these different versions are installed to meet the different requirements of certain programs.

Remember libraries are built using specific Python versions so if one is using such a library then the particular Python version for that library to work will have to be installed, for that reason python3 directory has the packages related to Py3 and the other directories python3.x has the different distributions.

Comment: `which python` doesnt return anything. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: That's because you dont have Python 2 installed, maybe you've uninstalled it, that's why `python --version` doesn't return anything. I missed that I'll update my answer.

Comment: How can we explain the remnants of python2 files given that I did not install python2 previously?

Comment: Python 2 comes installed out of the box with Ubuntu, the reason behind that is many (and I mean MANY) packages have been made with Py2 (some of which Ubuntu provides as a part of the fresh install). It is never advised to remove Py2 as you will need it sometime in the future. I learnt this the hard way once.

Comment: Make a habit of always using `python3` and `pip3` that would save you a lot of time and effort in the future. If you need anything else please ask. If this answer helped upvote and click on the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The python2.7 directory in `/usr/lib` contains all the default libraries of python as a part of python standard library. It might not be installed by default for the user session but since many system libraries of OS depend on python2, these libraries are installed.
2. Three python3 directories correspond to:

   - python3: contains distribution packages
   - python3.x: Python standard library of that particular version.

Since Python2 is not installed in a live session by default in Ubuntu 18.04. You will have to install it manually

```
$ sudo apt install python2.7-minimal
```

You can now use python2.7 using

```
$ python2.7
```

Comment: Does python2 has to be installed for these default libraries to be useful? I'm trying to understand why there is python2.7/ in /usr/lib/ when there is no python2 installed

Comment: So that system libraries which are dependent on python2.7 can use it.